# Refit exception system.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'M' is an invalid start of a value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5, refit

I am using Refit version 6.0.94. I have a .net 5.0 Api and a Blazor Server app .Net 5.0. The Api and Web app are both deployed in Linux containers. When running locally in visual studio (windows 10) I do not get the error.

The Get and Delete verbs are working fine, but the Patch and Post are failing with exception

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'M' is an invalid start of a value.
> Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.    --->
> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'M' is an invalid start of a
> value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
> at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader&
> json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
> in
> /*/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/ThrowHelper.cs:line
> 280
> at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker) in /*/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.cs:line
> 1034

The Api Code is Here

```
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<IActionResult> PatchAsync([FromBody] Customer customer)
{
   return Ok(await _service.PatchAsync(customer));
}
```

The Poco code as follows

```
namespace CustomerCare
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
                    
        [JsonPropertyName("Surname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
                
        [JsonPropertyName("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
            
        [JsonPropertyName("SignupDate")]
        public DateTime? SignupDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Refit setup and definition

```
services.AddRefitClient<ICustomerService>().ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myservername/api/v1"))
                    
public interface ICustomerService
{
    [Delete("/CustomerCare/")]
    Task<bool> DeleteCustomer(int id);

    [Patch("/CustomerCare/")]
    Task<bool> PatchCustomerAsync([Body] Customer customer);

    [Get("/CustomerCare/{id}")]
    Task<Customer> GetCustomerByIdAsync(int id);

    [Post("/CustomerCare/")]
    Task PostAsync([Body] Customer customer);
}
```

The calling code is as follows

```
    try
    {
        return await _customerService.PatchCustomerAsync(customer);
    }
    catch (ApiException ex)
    {
        var errors = await ex.GetContentAsAsync<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        var message = string.Join("; ", errors.Values);
        throw new Exception(message);
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at what the response is on the wire? It sounds like it's probably not valid JSON for whatever reason...

Comment: Echo that; pause the code at the point the response has been downloaded but not yet parsed.. you'll probably find out it's some plaintext like "Method not allowed"

Comment: but why would it work on windows?

Comment: Also the Api works fine from Postman and curl

Comment: i have seen people have had issues with Refit above v6. Strange that it works with windows and not Linux, is it something to do with quotes?